# Comparação de datas usando o TimeSpan.Compare()

Tags: c#

Estou tentando ver se um horário existe dentro de um range de horas iniciais e finais, mas estou com um problema de configurar a condição.

Exemplo

**Hora de parametro: 07:00:00**

**Hora inicial: 06:00:00**

**Hora final: 23:00:00**

Só que pelo meu código esse parametro nao entra no range, e o que realmente acontece é que ele inverte as entradas na condição, quando deveria entrar, ele sai e vice-versa.

Segue código:

```
  DateTime dtImportacao = new DateTime(2019,07,01,07,00,00);

            TimeSpan[] datasInicias = new TimeSpan[]
            {

            new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(00,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(23,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(19,00,01),
            new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(23,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(08,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(19,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(19,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(22,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(23,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(06,00,01)
        };
            TimeSpan[] datasFinais = new TimeSpan[]
            {
            new TimeSpan(23,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(23,59,59),
            new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(19,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(05,59,59),
            new TimeSpan(23,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(20,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(05,45,59),
            new TimeSpan(22,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
            new TimeSpan(22,59,59)
            };




            for (int i = 0; i < datasInicias.Length; i++)
            {


                if ((TimeSpan.Compare(dtImportacao.TimeOfDay, datasInicias[i]) == -1 || TimeSpan.Compare(dtImportacao.TimeOfDay, datasInicias[i]) == 0) ||  (TimeSpan.Compare(dtImportacao.TimeOfDay, datasFinais[i]) == 0 || TimeSpan.Compare(dtImportacao.TimeOfDay, datasFinais[i]) == 1))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Parametro de Comparação: {0}   | {1}  Até {2} Dentro do Range", dtImportacao.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), datasInicias[i], datasFinais[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Parametro de Comparação: {0}   | {1}  Até {2} Fora do Range", dtImportacao.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), datasInicias[i], datasFinais[i]);
                }
            }
```

Porém eu não sei de devo colocar na minha decisão todos os parametros do
[TimeSpan.Compare()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.timespan.compare?view=netframework-4.8) para validar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando os valores mencionados:

> Hora de parametro: 07:00:00
>
> Hora inicial: 06:00:00
>
> Hora final: 23:00:00

Você precisa que seu if seja ((07 >= 06) && (07 <= 23)) trocando isso para suas variaveis e utilizando o TimeSpan.Compare(), acredito que precise de algo assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < datasInicias.Length; i++)
{
    if ((TimeSpan.Compare(dtImportacao.TimeOfDay, datasInicias[i]) == 1 || TimeSpan.Compare(dtImportacao.TimeOfDay, datasInicias[i]) == 0) &&  
    (TimeSpan.Compare(dtImportacao.TimeOfDay, datasFinais[i]) == -1 || TimeSpan.Compare(dtImportacao.TimeOfDay, datasFinais[i]) == 0))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parametro de Comparação: {0}   | {1}  Até {2} Dentro do Range", dtImportacao.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), datasInicias[i], datasFinais[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parametro de Comparação: {0}   | {1}  Até {2} Fora do Range", dtImportacao.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), datasInicias[i], datasFinais[i]);
    }
}
```